# Multiple tags/right-justified text in unaligned environments using amsmath

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, amsmath

How can I use multiple tags or right-justified text elements in an equation environment with many lines while keeping all equations centered? Unfortunately, I can only use packages accepted by the [ACM TAPS system](https://www.acm.org/publications/taps/accepted-latex-packages). It would be great if you could provide answers for the aforementioned package list. But also general answers are very welcome!

So far I have the following:

```
\begin{gather*}
\begin{split}
 d(x) + e(x) + f(x) < a(x) * b(x) * c(x)  \\
      * d(x) * e(x) * f(x) \\ \hfill\text{Explained here}
\end{split}\\
\begin{split}
b(x) + c(x) + d(x) + e(x) + f(x) < a(x) * b(x) * c(x)  \\
      * d(x) * e(x) * f(x) \\ \hfill\text{And explained further here}
\end{split}
\end{gather*}
```

This keeps the equations centered, however, the text is not right justified but aligned to the right of the equation:

[image: Using split environment]

Also if I use the `align` environment, the equations are right-justified even without using an `&`:

```
\begin{align*}
d(x) + e(x) + f(x) < a(x) * b(x) * c(x) * d(x) \\
      * e(x) * f(x) \tag*{Explained here} \\
a(x) + b(x) + c(x) + d(x) + e(x) + f(x) < a(x) * b(x) * c(x)  \\
      * d(x) * e(x) * f(x) \tag*{And explained further here}
\end{align*}
```

[image: Using align environment]

Note: I don't want to use the `&` because the equations have different lengths on the left side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you want? I used `\shortintertext` from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\begin{split}
 d(x) + e(x) + f(x) < a(x) * b(x) * c(x) \\
     {} * d(x) * e(x) * f(x)
\end{split}
\shortintertext{\raggedleft Explained here}
\begin{split}
b(x) + c(x) + d(x) + e(x) + f(x) < a(x) * b(x) * c(x) \\
     {} * d(x) * e(x) * f(x) 
\end{split}
\shortintertext{\raggedleft And explained further here}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*: another possible code, with only `amsmath`:

```
   \begin{gather*}
    \begin{split}
     d(x) + e(x) + f(x) < a(x) * b(x) * c(x) \\
         {} * d(x) * e(x) * f(x)
    \end{split}\\
    \makebox[\textwidth][r]{Explained here}\\
    \begin{split}
    b(x) + c(x) + d(x) + e(x) + f(x) < a(x) * b(x) * c(x) \\
         {} * d(x) * e(x) * f(x)
    \end{split}\\
    \makebox[\textwidth][r]{And explained further here}
    \end{gather*}
```

Comment: Yes, but forgot to mention that I can only use a certain list of packages, mathtools unfortunately is not a part of it :( Nevertheless, it does help a lot!

Comment: It's only an extension of amsmath (and a quite useful one!). You can use  `\intertext`, but will have to adjust the vertical spacing by hand.

Comment: The edited version is perfect! Thanks a lot